# Hide single markergroup on mapstart

Tags: javascript, google-maps, types, toggle, marker

I createt a map wich hide/shows markers by their type on toggle.
Now i want to hide a group (type) of marker on mapstart and only show it when a button is clicked. So i want the the group (buche) isn´t shown after map is starting.
Hm i dont get it what i am doing wrong.. Anybody a solution?

```
    markerGroups = { "buche": [], "birke": [], "erle": [], "haselnuss": [], "rotbuche": [], "weide": [], "tanne": [], "lärche": [], "eibe": [], "walnuss": []};



 function createMarker(latlng, name, address, tel, href, image, type) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: images[type],
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });



      markerGroups[type].push(marker);

for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[type].length; i++) {

        var marker = markerGroups["buche"];
            marker.setMap(null);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the map-property to null when you create the marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: (type==='buche') ? null : map,
    icon: images[type],
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });
```

Comment: good evening Molle. I would have a tricky Question to you. Its about reading a XML in google maps and the image preload. I think you are the right man to ask :) This was asked today ans i need exactly the same ! Here goes the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077455/don%C2%B4t-preload-images-in-xml-google-maps-api-v3 THank you m8

Comment: @Manuel: I answered the linked question, there is no problem with the image-preload.